# NGINX in Docker shows wrong IP in $remote_addr

Tags: nginx

On a Synology-NAS I got NGINX in Docker to forward requests to services. 
The services are running in Docker too.
Yesterday, I wanted to make use of fail2ban and found wrong IPs in the watched service-logs.

After checking NGINX logs I noticed that the logged IPs are not the real external/visitor IPs:

```
172.28.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2023:12:48:04 +0000] "POST /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/2.0" 200 8170 "https://service.domain.de/accounts/login/?next=/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0" "-"
```

Every IP that shows up there is **172.28.0.1** - regardless of the service I connect to.
Therefore it seems like NGINX is the problem. But why?

**My Setup:**
Synology NAS runs behind my router and gets 80/443 forwarded by router.
Ports 80/443 are open in Synology NAS firewall and hit the NGINX-Container Port configuration:

```
0.0.0.0:443 -> 443/tcp
0.0.0.0:80 -> 80/tcp
```

**The Network-Configuration of my running NGINX container shows:**

```
Connection to Network "paperless_services":
IP 192.168.144.10 / Gateway 192.168.144.1

Connection to Network "nginx1:":
Container-IP 172.28.0.2 / Gateway 172.28.0.1
```

(Docker-Network "nginx1:" is used by all sevice-containers for communitcation.)

**The Network-Copfiguration of my running SERVICE container (paperless) shows:**

```
Connection to Network "paperless_services:":
Container-IP 192.168.144.5 / Gateway 192.168.144.1
```

I have found some questions here that go in same direction but I couldn't find a solution.
Anything I do: Logs show only IP 172.28.0.1

I hope someone can help me with that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, bad news ....

Hunting down that issue I landet [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15086).

The problem is, that my NGINX runs in a docker-container which ist connected via bridge-network to the world.
Therefore NAT takes place before NGINX handles the incoming request. In result the visiors IP ($REMOTE_ADDR) gets replaced by the bridge gateway and is lost.

The link above shows some ideas how this can be worked around. But none of them are easy or a "perfect" solution.
Best would be to run NGINX in docker connected only to the host-network (but you cant connect to HOST-Network and BRIDGE-network at the same time!!) OR to run NGINX on another device (bare metal / no docker).

Sometimes life isn't fair :/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. I have the same issue, but only in Windows, meanwhile in Linux it works fine.